# How do I replace cell values in pandas dataframe with the filename?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm appending several CSV files into one data frame, to then export into a combined CSV file. However, I need to replace the value "DTL" in the first column of each file with the filename so that the resulting data can still be tied back to each file.

Here's an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

all_files=glob.glob("*.csv")
li=[]

for filename in all_files:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None,header=None,sep='\t')
    dfproper=df.drop(0,0)
    dfproper.replace(to_replace="DTL",value=os.path.basename(filename),inplace=True)
    li.append(dfproper)

df_final=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
df_final.to_csv("Combined.csv",index=None,header=None,sep='\t')
```

The code doesn't give me any errors in this form but also doesn't replace the "DTL" values.

Comment: Can't see any problem with the code. Maybe you can generate some input data and expected output to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try generating a small dataframe to work with since the data I'm using is usually quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution to this.

The separator I was using was '\t' for Tab, but as these are csvs they're quite literally comma separated. So I needed to omit the "sep" parameter, which then allowed the "DTL" to match the "to_replace" parameter.

I also cleaned the code up a bit by omitting the dropped header in the pd.read step.

Here's an example of the finished product.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

all_files=glob.glob("*.csv")
li=[]

for filename in all_files:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None,header=None,skiprows=1,low_memory=False)
    df.replace("DTL",os.path.basename(filename),inplace=True)
    li.append(df)

df_final=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
df_final.to_csv("DHLE_20211114.csv",index=None,header=None)
df_final.head
```

Thanks to everyone who commented!